# Adding reference to Custom component

Tags: react-native

Referring [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements) library and using its checkbox component.

```
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
       checked: true
       titleText1:"Checkbox one"
       titleText1:"Checkbox two"
     }
   }
  render() 
  {
     return (
            <View>
  <CheckBox ref='chk1' checked={this.state.checked} title={this.state.titleText1}  />
  <CheckBox ref='chk2' checked={this.state.checked} title={this.state.titleText2}   onPress={this.manageChkboxes()} />
             </View> );
 }

  manageChkboxes(){
  this.state.checked=false
  this.state.titleText1="Checkbox one updated"
  this.state.titleText2= "Checkbox two updated"
    this.refs.chk1.checked= this.state.checked;
    this.refs.chk1.title= this.state.titleText1;
    this.refs.chk2.checked= this.state.checked;
    this.refs.chk2.title= this.state.titleText2;
  }
```

I am not able to modify component properties by using reference to it. On calling manageChkboxes() function it gives error:`null is not an object(evaluating 'this.refs.chk1.checked=!1')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the props, you would have to change it a little. But you should also not use strings for refs, Also never change state directly, always use setState:

```
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
       checked: true
       titleText1:"Checkbox one"
       titleText1:"Checkbox two"
     }
   }

  manageChkboxes(){
  this.setState({
    checked: false,
    titleText1: "Checkbox one updated"
  )};
  }

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <CheckBox checked={this.state.checked} title={this.state.titleText1}  />
      <CheckBox checked={this.state.checked} title={this.state.titleText2}   onPress={this.manageChkboxes()} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: also, you should not be changing properties like this, you should have a variable for the property and have managechkboxes update that variable. (you would most likely need to use state to cause a re-render with the new values)

Comment: its giving error `undefined is not an object(evaluating this.chk1.props). Will update my question as per your suggestion

Comment: You need to return your checkbox components in the render() or else they're never being rendered. Ill update my answer.

Comment: setState re-renders components so it works, I am trying to do it using reference to component. Isn't that possible

Comment: yes you can, but you shouldn't be really updating the component through references, just grabbing properties or methods that belong to the component.